# The differences between two versions of Recursion Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recursion

**Version 1:**

> For any set $A$, any $a\in A$, and any function $g:A\times \Bbb N\to A$, there exists a unique infinite sequence $f:\Bbb N\to A$ such that
>
> (1) $f_0=a$;
>
> (2) $f_{n+1}=g(f_n,n)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$

**Version 2:**

> Let $G$ be an operation. For any set $a$, there exists a unique infinite sequence $(f_n\mid n\in\Bbb N)$ such that
>
> (1) $f_0=a$;
>
> (2) $f_{n+1}=G(f_n,n)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$

---

Of my understanding, the input of **Version 1** are two factors: a set and one of its elements, while that of **Version 2** is just one factor: a set. Maybe I'm wrong, but I feel that they are quite similar.

My questions:

1. Are there more fundamental differences of these two versions?
2. Please give me an simple-to-understand example where one version is still valid to apply, while the other is not. (I'm just exposed to Transfinite Induction/Recursion, so I'm afraid that I'm unable to grasp advanced examples).

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, **version 2** doesn't make a lot of sense, because you never say what $A$ is nor where the operation $G$ is defined. And if, as I suspect, $A$ is an arbitrary set, $a$ is an element of $A$, and $G$ is a function from $A\times\mathbb N$ into $A$, the **version 2** becomes **version 1**.

Comment: I'm sorry! I mistyped the **Version 2**. I have edited it. Please have a look!

Comment: Actually, my textbook doesn't define $G$. From the context, it seems to me that $G$ is a class function from the class of all sets to the class of all sets.

Comment: @LeAnhDung It still doesn't say where is that $G$ is defined.

Comment: I also have no idea how $G$ is defined since my textbook just says *Let $G$ be an operation*. In my textbook *Introduction to Set Theory* by Hrbacek and Jech, the authors prove the **Version 2** by Transfinite Recursion.